# What is the "-shi" ending's meaning?

Tags: japanese-language, wixoss

This isn't the first time I hear this peculiar ending "-shi" added to words. It usually appears at the end of sentences. From the looks of it, the ending is supposed to make the speaker sound lighthearted, friendly, humorous. As an example, in *Selector Infected/Spread WIXOSS* Eldora and Chiyori both talk and behave peculiarly, using this ending.

What is the actual purpose of it?

Comment: I have a feeling that real Japanese people don't actually use sentence-ending _-shi_. This is probably just one of those anime things, like [_-nya_](http://myanimelist.net/character/81373/Nyanta) and [_-fumo_](http://myanimelist.net/character/105601/Moffle).

Comment: It certainly doesn't feel like something an ordinary person would use when speaking to coworkers, perhaps, but it feels like one of those things that appear in comical fiction.

Comment: https://glim-re.glim.gakushuin.ac.jp/bitstream/10959/2191/1/kokugokokubungaku_52_1_15.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"-desushi" mean "becase" and "and".

Let's take a look at a few quotes from episode 5 for example.

> ふぉぉぉ！燃える展開です!!
>   ちよりはバーニングチョリソー**ですしー**!!

Wow! This is a burning development!! **Because** Chiyori is Burning Chorizo!!

> るぅ子さんがやらないなら私がやります
>   ちよりがやりたい**ですしー**！

If Ruuko doesn't play, I'll play.
**Because** Chiyori want to play!

The word "-desushi" itself is normal Japanese.
But the overusing "-desushi" is part of slang of young people.

In this anime, "-desushi" is used for accent of character like "-nyo".